# How can I update a table in which I make a SELECT query? (Error #1093)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run this:

```
$stmt=$cxn->prepare("UPDATE table1 SET used='1' WHERE prim_id != 
     (SELECT MAX(prim_id) FROM table1 WHERE email='email12345@gmail.com')");
$stmt->execute(array());
```

But it results in a MySQL error: `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause`.

After searching this error, it seems that `In MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part.`.

How can I change that query to make it work?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: "it doesn't work" doesn't explain what your problem is: crash? unexpected result? nothing is updated? too many records are updated?

Comment: Hi, it results in a PHP fatal error and when I try to run it in MysQL, it says `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table1 t1, (SELECT MAX(prim_id) AS max_prim_id
                     FROM table1 WHERE email='email12345@gmail.com') tmp
SET t1.used='1'
WHERE t1.prim_id != tmp.max_prim_id
AND t1.`email` = 'email12345@gmail.com'
```

It removes the subquery and uses a regular temporary table to store the result of table "tmp".
The query takes 2 tables for update:

- table1 (with the alias t1)
- a temporary table (with the alias tmp)

The WHERE clause:

- indicates how the two tables are joined
- restricts the records to consider in table t1

The SET clause says that only t1.used will be updated.

[UPDATE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)

Comment: Hi Jocelyn, Thanks a lot for your response. It did solve it. I am just trying to understand what you did: does `UPDATE table1 t1, max_prim_id tmp` mean that you are *duplicating* table1 and max_prim_id into t1 and tmp respectively? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Your query is just missing some logic. Change it to:

```
UPDATE table1
SET used='1'
WHERE `email` = 'email12345@gmail.com'
  AND prim_id != (
    SELECT MAX(prim_id) 
    FROM table1
    WHERE email='email12345@gmail.com')
```